# Video player not playing videos under Webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, html, webdriver

We noticed that if we run out test cases (which include a case where an html5 video player plays a video for a couple of seconds) the video player frame show up but no video is loaded and played, showing a black background instead of the video. But if we play it manually, it plays normally after loading the video. So we think it has something to do with the way Webdriver works. Hopefully someone has a clue for us.

The code we assume is correct, because the player opens, it waits for the ammount of seconds specified and then closed okay, so its not something wrong in the code we assume, the player is the www.dashif.org player in google chrome and a propietary flash-based player in firefox.

Chrome player:
http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html

Comment: I see the following messages when i enter the console in the browser: http://pastebin.com/k8UtiM36

Comment: and here's the output without webdriver, "manual" http://pastebin.com/EKYtMfFf I noticed that in the error log it says: `1436955523.js:788 DRM: KeySystem Access Denied! -- Key system access denied!`, and running manually, it says: `KeySystem Access Granted (com.widevine.alpha)!`

Comment: I haded the following code `caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"excludeSwitches" => [ "disable-component-update" ]})
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' desired_capabilities: caps` but i'm now getting `C:/Users/usuario/Planes/QA-Pruebas Automatizadas/Webdriver/suites/spec/1.4/tests/test1.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
...44/wd/hub' desired_capabilities: caps
...                               ^`

Comment: I've discovered that its a windows chromedriver problem, because the same test case in linux, worked perfectly. I will be running the test cases in linux for the time being, until i could find a workaround.